# Using setInterval with socket.write

Tags: node.js, sockets, client, setinterval

This is the code that works but it writes the data just once:

```
var net = require('net');
var PORT = 3000;
var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(PORT, function(){
  client.write('{printing}');
})
```

I am looking to write the same thing every few seconds. Wrote the below code but it doesn't seem to work:

```
client.connect(PORT, function(){
   setInterval(function(){
     client.write('{ printing }');
   },10000);
 })
```

Following is the error that I keep getting:

```
node:events:355
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write EPIPE
    at afterWriteDispatched (node:internal/stream_base_commons:160:15)
    at writeGeneric (node:internal/stream_base_commons:151:3)
    at Socket._writeGeneric (node:net:773:11)
    at Socket._write (node:net:785:8)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:395:12)
    at Socket.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:340:10)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/app/src/index.js:135:14)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:188:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:153:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21) {
  errno: -32,
  code: 'EPIPE',
  syscall: 'write'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting..
```

This is how I fixed it:

```
client.connect(PORT, function(){
    client.write('printing')
  })

  //adding drain if the buffer gets full
  client.on('drain',()=>{
    console.log("draining the buffer")
    setTimeout(() => {
        client.write('printing')
    })

    //reading the response recieved : ("ok")
  client.on('data', (data) => {})

  //in case of an error, closing the connection
  client.on('error',err => {}).on('close',() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      client.connect(PORT, function(){
        client.write('printing')
  
      })
    },40000)
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, the EPIPE error probably means that you're trying to write to a socket that has been closed.  Since the `setInterval()` example you show keeps going forever, that probably means that the socket you originally connected gets closed at some point, but your `setInterval()` is still firing and trying to write to it.

You don't show the overall context of what you're trying to accomplish here to know exactly what to suggest, but at a minimum, you need to call `clearInterval()` to stop the timer whenever the socket it's trying to write to gets closed, either on purpose or because of error.

Here's an example for how you could debug if this is what is happening to you:

```
const net = require('net');
const PORT = 3000;
const client = new net.Socket();
let timer;

function disableTimer() {
   if (timer) {
       clearInterval(timer);
       timer = null;
   }
}

client.on('error', err => {
    console.log("socket error", err);
    disableTimer();
}).on('close', () => {
    console.log("socket closed");
    disableTimer();
});

client.connect(PORT, function(){
   timer = setInterval(function(){
     client.write('{ printing }');
   },10000);
});
```

Comment: That is all the code I have for this. I am not explicitly closing the connection. 
What I am trying to do is, have this "printing" message sent every 10 seconds over the port 3000.

Comment: @user5235751 - Maybe the other end is closing it or getting an error. You can find out by listening for both error and close events and logging.  This is basic debugging.

Comment: @user5235751 - See debugging code I added to my answer.

Comment: You were right, the issue was that every time something was sent over the connection, an "ok" message was sent back and the connection closed thereafter. Hence the broken pipe error. Edited the question with a solution

Comment: @user5235751 - Since it looks like you may be new here, if this answer helped you figure out the problem, then you can indicate that to the community here by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.